# Confirmed features of .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

Does anyone know what will be in .NET 4.0?

I found [tuples on codeplex](https://mef.svn.codeplex.com/svn/src/ComponentModel/System/Tuple.cs):

```
....
// NOTE : this is a TEMPORARY and a very minimalistic implementation of Tuple'2, 
// as defined in http://devdiv/sites/docs/NetFX4/CLR/Specs/Base Class Libraries/Tuple Spec.docx
// We will remove this after we move to v4 and Tuple is actually in there
public struct Tuple<TFirst, TSecond>
....
```

Answer (score 3):

[Parallel Extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/10/10/8994927.aspx)

[WCF/WF improvements](http://blogs.msdn.com/wenlong/archive/2008/09/07/net-4-0-wf-wcf-and-oslo.aspx)

I expect BigInteger will be back, too. I'd really like to see a bunch of the F# immutable collections become part of ".NET proper" too - and that wouldn't surprise me at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the usage of *dynamic* keyword in C# 4.0 from [Anders Hejlsberg's JAOO talk](http://jaoo.blip.tv/file/1317881/). It allows calling methods in a late-bindish way which will really help in COM interop scenarios.

Usage:

```
// Instead of this:
object calc = GetCalculator();
Type calcType = calc.GetType();
object res = calcType.InvokeMember("Add", 
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
    new int[] { 10, 20 });
int sum = Convert.ToInt32(res);

// you can write this:
dynamic calc = GetCalculator();
int sum = calc.Add(10, 20);
```

[Static and Dynamic http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9469/dynamicxf4.png](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9469/dynamicxf4.png)

Answer (score 1):

[Glenn Block](http://blogs.msdn.com/gblock/) confirmed on a recent [Herding Code](http://herdingcode.com/) episode that [MEF](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF) would be part of .NET 4.0.