# What are the major differences between NET Frameworks 3.5 and 4.0?

Tags: .net-3.5, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Things in .NET Framework 4 that every programmer should know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690386/things-in-net-framework-4-that-every-programmer-should-know)
>   [Basic difference between .net 3.5 and 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000101/basic-difference-between-net-3-5-and-4-0)

Hi Guys

Is there any real great (really good) difference between NET Framework 3.5 and NET Framework 4.0?

Perhaps something regarding performance?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000101/basic-difference-between-net-3-5-and-4-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me personally, the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) will be a huge help.

For a more general answer you should check out these related questions:

- [Things in .NET Framework 4 that every programmer should know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690386/things-in-net-framework-4-that-every-programmer-should-know).
- [Confirmed features of .NET 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237041/confirmed-features-of-net-4-0)
- [Basic difference between .net 3.5 and 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000101/basic-difference-between-net-3-5-and-4-0)
- [What will be the new features available in ASP.Net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894543/what-will-be-the-new-features-available-in-asp-net-4-0)
- [Multithreading improvements in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704583/multithreading-improvements-in-net-4)